# C# Modify List item while in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, foreach

as the title say's I am attempting to get to edit a *list item* inside of a `foreach` loop. I know it is *not possible*, so I am asking for solutions to *work around* this.

As this is taking data directly from a MySQL server, it need's to be done inside of this loop and with the correct indexes.
I attempted to use a second list and change the data outside of the foreach loop, but that did not account for the index positions of the items.

```
foreach (string friend in friendsOnline)
{
    query = "SELECT `username` FROM `accounts` WHERE email = '" + friend + "'";
    
    cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<friendsOnline.Count; i++)
        {
            if (friendsOnline[i].Contains(friend))
            {
                friendsOnline[i] = rdr[0].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why not use a for-loop instead of foreach?

Comment: Holy sql injection vulnerability, Batman.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn To be honest, I'm not really bothered if user's decide to add a random email address to their friend's list.

Comment: @Luke You can use this to do a lot more than just add random emails addresses... for example, I could absolutely use the exact code in your question to drop every table your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see, you have emails in the `friendsOnline`:

```
string[] friendsOnline = new[] {
  "Me@Shire.com",
  "Dark.Lord@Mordor.gov",
};
```

and you want to change these *emails* into *names*:

```
string[] friendsOnline = new[] {
  "Frodo Baggins",
  "Sauron the Black",
};
```

First of all, I suggest executing *query* just once: SQL is too slow to be run in a loop; instead you can build a *dictionary* which eMail corresponds to which indexes:

```
using System.Linq;

...

// eMail - indexes correspondence
Dictionary<string, int[]> dict = friendsOnline
  .Select((name, index) => (name : name, index : index))
  .GroupBy(pair => pair.name, pair => pair.index, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
  .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.ToArray());

// We take all users (no WHERE), but once
// We read both username and email
string sql = 
  @"SELECT `username`,
           `email` 
      FROM `accounts`";
                
//DONE: using - we should Dispose IDisposable Command and Reader
using cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
using rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (rdr.Read()) {
  string name = Convert.ToString(rdr[0]);
  string mail = Convert.ToString(rdr[1]); 

  // If we have correspondent indexes, we change friendsOnline
  if (dict.TryGetValue(mail, out var indexes))
    foreach (var index in indexes)
      friendsOnline[index] = name;
}
```

Comment: Hi Dmitry, this does not work in this instance, as the email is pulled beforehand from another MySQL Table. As well as, rdr[1] does not exist, since it is only searching for the username, it will only return rdr index 0.

Comment: @Luke: As I can see from the query in the question, `email` is a field of `account` query. I've rewritten the query: I've dropped `WHERE` but add `email` to `SELECT`. Note, that now query have `2` fields, that's why `rdr[1]` exists (and equals to `email`)

Comment: I see yes, however Dictionary throw's an error with "using the generic type dictionary requires 2 type arguments"
I have not used Dictionary before, do you know the issue here?

Comment: @Luke: Sorry, it should be `Dictionary<string, int[]>`

Comment: @Luke If the emails also came from a MySql table, you should have pulled down the names _in the same query_.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn They come from two different tables, I cannot take the name down as there will be a data conflict with the original query.

Comment: Modifying the original query is exactly what I'm suggesting. Bring down the extra field earlier in your process, and do a little extra work there in how you retrieve and save the data if needed. Two different tables is irrelevant. That's what JOINs are for. These changes will easily speed up this process by at least an order of magnitude.